# Finding Duplicates with xsl:key?

Tags: xml, xslt

The following code works to output bag numbers in "g" found in other groups. Is there any way to achieve the same using `xsl:key`? Ideally "g" would be a parameter so I don't have to repeat similar code for "h", "i", etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <g>
        <bagn>A</bagn>
        <bagn>B</bagn>
    </g>
    <h>
        <bagn>C</bagn>
        <bagn>D</bagn>
        <bagn>A</bagn>
    </h>
    <i>
        <bagn>B</bagn>
        <bagn>F</bagn>
        <bagn>G</bagn>
    </i>
</root>
```

```
         <xsl:variable name="gDups">
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/g/bagn[.=/root/node()[not(self::g)]/bagn]">
               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                     <xsl:value-of select="concat('|',.,'|')"/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'|')"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:variable>
         
         <xsl:value-of select="$gDups"/>
```

Comment: Have you looked at an introduction to keys in XSLT to give it a try?  As for using a parameter for `g`, also tell us which version of XSLT and/or which XSLT processor you use.

Comment: I am using XSLT version 1 for Xalan

Comment: How exactly do you intend to pass the parameter? As a string containing the name of an element? Can there be two sibling elements with the same name?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to pass it as parameter. That's part of my question.

Comment: What is the result that you want? It is not too difficult to generate a list of duplicates for each child of `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="bagn" match="bagn" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <duplicates>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <!-- duplicates in siblings -->
            <xsl:variable name="dups" select="key('bagn', bagn)[not(generate-id(..) = generate-id(current()))]" />
            <xsl:if test="$dups">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$dups">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">|</xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </duplicates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<duplicates>
  <g>A|B</g>
  <h>A</h>
  <i>B</i>
</duplicates>
```

---

Note that this returns a list of duplicates in other siblings, even if the siblings have the same name. For example, for input of:

```
<root>
    <g>
        <bagn>A</bagn>
        <bagn>B</bagn>
    </g>
    <g>
        <bagn>C</bagn>
        <bagn>D</bagn>
        <bagn>A</bagn>
    </g>
    <g>
        <bagn>B</bagn>
        <bagn>F</bagn>
        <bagn>G</bagn>
    </g>
</root>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<duplicates>
  <g>A|B</g>
  <g>A</g>
  <g>B</g>
</duplicates>
```

Comment: "even if siblings have the same name", got it. Thanks.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: Yes, I am taking my time to digest it, since it has two concepts I've barely used: key and generate-id and you are using it in a very unorthodox way... at least for me. Thanks a lot. I wonder if the key was actually needed in this case or if it is must to have to get that result.

Comment: It could be done without the key (I think), but keys are the optimal way to resolve cross-references. I would have used it even if your question didn't mention it.

Comment: Also it is quite common to use generate-id() to establish that two nodes are the same (c.f. http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). In Xalan you can also take advantage of some extension functions for this purpose.